# giving border style with onclick jquery event filtering changing src

Tags: jquery, css, model-view-controller, filter, onclick

I have a product detail page. One big photo and other photos in small. When I click other small photos, I can see big photo changes to selected one. But at the same time I want to see that selected small photo border to be stand out with border style. But I couldnt do it. Can any one help please? Thanks for your helps.

this is my jquery

```
  @section FotoDegis
{
  <script src="~/Content/Default/js/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    function FotoDegis(value) 
    {
        $('#big-photo').attr("src", value);
        $(".product-photo-other-img img[src*='value']").css("border", "solid");
    }
  </script>
}
<section>
```

And this is  my view;

```
        <div class="product-photo">
            <div class="product-photo-main">
                <img id="big-photo" src="~/ProductPhotos/Normal/@Model.Photos.First().PhotoPath" alt="" />
            </div>

            <div id="similar-product" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">

                <div class="product-photo-other-container">
                    @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Photos.Count; i++)
                    {
                        if (i > 2)
                        {

                        }
                        else
                        {
                            <div class="product-photo-other">
                                <div class="product-photo-other-img" id=@i>
                                    <img id=@i onclick="FotoDegis(this.src, @i)" src="~/ProductPhotos/Normal/@(Model.Photos.Count >i ? Model.Photos[i].PhotoPath :"Resim_yok.gif" )" alt="" />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        }

                    }
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: if FotoDegis function try changing the jquery seletor to this `$(".product-photo-other-img img[src*='"+value+"']").css("border", "solid");`

Comment: Use [unobtrusive javascript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript)  - remove the `.onclick` and add a class name (say) `class="smallimage"` - then `$('.smallimage').click(function() { $('#big-photo').attr('src', $(this).attr('src')); $(this).css('border', 'solid'); });`